# How to refer to males and females in a trans-positive world?

Tags: gender-politics, gender-positive, sex-vs-gender, social-gender

I have a presentation coming up with a big client. One of the executives I'm presenting to is a transgender person. For context, I'm in sales and marketing - I make TV commercials.

In the meeting I need to talk about a script involving male and female actors. I have to explain why we'll use a male actor for 'part 2', and a female actor for part 1.

I'm nervous about using the word "gender" or "male" or "female" or any other word like that. I  know  that using gendered words can be offensive these days, especially to trans individuals, but I don't know which words exactly are offensive. Internet search only brings up results for how to refer to transgendered persons specifically, not how to refer to non-transgender people. I can't figure out for the life of me how to discuss this subject without breaking the rules.

Hope somebody out there can help. Which words should I avoid, and what words can I use without being insensitive?

Comment: As long as the actors are not trans or otherwise alternatively gendered, just use the language you would normally use.

Comment: How do you think they might address this problem, or attach any significance to it in a country like Malawi, where the average GDP per capita is $226 per annum per head - significantly less than people pay for a gym membership in Europe or America? I just wish people would focus on the real world for a few minutes. What does it matter?

Comment: If trans-gender individuals are offended about gender words, that's their problem, not yours. They have a right to be concerned about the contents of the script, however, and may bring their own point of view into the discussion. They have a duty to be professional about it, though.

Comment: This is the first time I am hearing that calling a male person "male" (or a female person "female") can be offensive to anyone. Especially when their gender is relevant to their role.

Comment: @WS2 and mick In a question on an English Language Usage forum about political correctness in the workplace, in the context of presenting to an executive who may well be sensitive to certain types of language, your answer is "this type of political correctness is bullshit, if they're offended that's their problem"? Regardless of the truth or lack thereof in that statement, it's not an answer to the question, just soapboxing.

Comment: @Some_Guy well. As far as English is concerned, that *is* the answer to the question. And this site is about English. It is not about political correctness. If I am nervous about using the words "male actor" to refer to a male actor, that *is* bullshit, and I am best advised to visit a psychiatrist, not a linguist.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Would you post the same comment to someone asking whether or not "black" was acceptable usage in a boardroom to refer to a person? How about "negro"? Political correctness, and what likelihood certain terms have of offending people is not transparent to everyone who isn't "in the loop". It's also not always particularly based in logic, as evidenced by the fact that in many languages the offensiveness between "black" and "negro" is the other way round to English.  This question is a broad one about what gendered language is likely to offend a trans person, not a political statement.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Is it that "offensive" to you that someone might ask an English language forum about appropriate language in the workplace, that you felt the need to close the question? The questioner said "using gendered words can be offensive these days [...] but I don't know which words exactly are offensive." In what sense is this "off-topic"? O do you just personally find political correctness distasteful? The fact is that, linguistically, words with the same denotation have a different connotation.There are polite and impolite ways of speaking, and that distinction is perfectly on-topic here.

Comment: @Some_Guy I believe we should show the greatest respect for others when describing people who are ethnically, gendered, or oriented differently to us. I would extend this to transgendered people, using the gendered words with which they identify. But to be expected to avoid the use of male or female when talking about anyone else in their presence, is beyond ridiculous.

Comment: @WS2 I agree.  But aside from the part about those specific words, the questioner also asked in general how to approach gender and language in this context.  I don't see how that's off-topic

Comment: @RegDwigнt your comment that I should see a psychiatrist for asking how the English language has evolved to include an entirely new class of individuals is pretty overtly reactionary but funny in a way too. You are clearly looking for your own answers and projecting your quest onto others. Don't worry. You're not alone....
And it was you who closed the topic down, right? Ha... How does someone like you obtain the power to close forum topics unilaterally anyway? Did you kill your competition to win the title? I retract my earlier statement.. Enjoy your loneliness. This forum is clearly flawed

Answer (score 1):

Political correctness with regards to gender identity is a relatively new thing for many people (and seems to have come from nothing to widespread a lot quicker than it did with, say, sexuality).  This can make it seem like a bit of a minefield, not wanting to step somewhere that might cause offence by saying something that until recently would have seemed perfectly normal.  However, while this more trans-accepting type of language may seem daunting, it isn't that complicated.

Firstly, let's start nice and easy, words like tranny and ladyboy are out. But that's probably no surprise.

Secondly, the biggest most significant change that (while has existed for a long time in the language) is relatively new in common parlance, is the meaning distinction between "gender" and "sex". Simply put, gender is the outward way someone identifies and sex is biological; the stuff between the legs.  All you have to remember is to refer to someone according to their **gender** not their **sex**.  So if you are in a meeting with someone who is born of the male sex, but outwardly identifies as female, you call them "woman", "her" and "she". And Jenny, not Steve.

Other than that, you're good.  By saying you want a male actor to play a man, because the character is a man, you're not likely to offend anyone.  I can't see how anything other than regular language could be cause for offense here.

*[There's some other stuff about non gender binary people and using "they" for people in-between or outside the gender binary, but this is not really relevant to you, and is much more fraught with tumblr taking things too far (although non-binary neither male nor female people obviously exist, dealing with that in language is still a little unresolved.)]*

Comment: Now, if you stumble and try and mince your words and say "we want someone who is a woman, you know, like in the sense of identity or how they look or whatever, I'm not saying you're not a woman... anyway, so we..." then you're looking a bit like Ricky Gervais in the UK office trying to talk to a black guy.  You'll be alright, just be natural

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. I asked the community here to avoid just those kinds of Ricky Gervais moments. . .

So, to double check, a statement like this would be okay:

"We'll have two actors for this part, a male and a female, to balance the representation and expand the reach."
?

Comment: @RickSterling - Yes, it's as simple as that.  They way you refer to genders should be no different to how you normally refer to them (assuming you're usually polite/respectful of course).  When referring to your transgender guest, just be guided by their name ("Jackie" is female, "Jack" is male).  Personally, I'd be led by "Jack" being male, even if he's wearing a dress unless she corrects you.

Comment: @Pete I'd absolutely go with this. Just talk about gender normally, while including people who identify as a gender other than the one they were assigned at birth in the category they identify as.  Just like normal, John's a man, Cathy is a girl.  Cathy may or may not have been born as a Steve, but unless it's relevant to the conversation, doesn't need to be mentioned. Saying "men" or "women" isn't offensive unless you follow that with some "and I mean REAL men amirite?", which obviously no one would do by mistake

Comment: @RickSterling  I hope this has been helpful to you, and I'm sorry that this question has been shut down to people who may well be better at answering it than I. Seems like this forum has a lot of people who can't see the irony in behaving exactly like the supposed PC police they so hate, i.e. aggressively shutting down a conversation that doesn't meet their political perspective.  Seems like caring about being politically correct (or even just curious about how not to offend someone) is becoming politically incorrect in itself on much of the internet these days.

Comment: @Some_Guy This has definitely been helpful to me. The meeting went well thanks to your help. 

I am new to the forum, but I believe my question does relate to the English language. In a sense, it's a real-time etymological question: how has the language recently evolved to include a group of people whose existence wasn't acknowledged when I was in school.